# A alone takes $a$ more days than A and B, and B alone takes $b$ more days than A and B. Find how long for A and B.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, word-problem

---

[image: img1]

What's said in the box is not clear. The author meant to say,

> If A working alone takes *a* days more than A and B together, and B working alone takes *b* days more than A and B together, then the number of days taken by A and B working together is given by $\sqrt{ab}$.

Also, I think that the result of the provided example should be 6 hours and not 6 days because $a$ and $b$ are given in hours.

I'd like to know where $\sqrt{ab}$ comes from. So far, It's the only formula I haven't been able to derive myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let A and B together = $x$ days

A alone = $a + x$ days

B alone = $b + x$ days

Per day work of A + Per day work of B = per day work of A + B

$\frac{1}{a+x} + \frac{1}{b+x} = \frac{1}{x}$

We get $(a + b + 2x)x = (a+x)(b+x) \implies x^2 = ab$

Comment: Spare a moment to read https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Literary_Lapses/A,_B,_and_C